# Why does GmailDraft.send() make the draft's gmail labels disappear?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

On a google script, I do the following: create a draft, apply a label to it, send the draft. Then when I check the sent email in my gmail account, the label is gone!

My question: why would that be the case?

Here is the code (I have checked the label is applied correctly before sending happens):

```
var draft = GmailApp.createDraft("test@gmail.com", "Email Subject", "Email Body");
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Label Name");
label.addToThread(draft.getMessage().getThread());
draft.send();
```

This is surprising especially because sending a draft manually in gmail does NOT remove labels in this manner.

Of course a way of getting around this problem is adding the label after sending (as below), but for my purposes this isn't convenient, and it still leaves the question as to why the label disappears unanswered...

```
var draft = GmailApp.createDraft("test@gmail.com", "Email Subject", "Email Body");
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Label Name");
var message = draft.send();
label.addToThread(message.getThread());
```

Comment: Apps Script is not the Gmail UI. Generally you must remember that a draft and the sent draft are two wholly different MIME messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/labels#applying_labels_to_messages_and_threads) where it says that:

> Messages and threads can have multiple labels associated with them;
>   however, **draft messages cannot have labels applied to them**. Modifying
>   the labels applied to a thread applies or removes the specified labels
>   from all messages in the thread. You can modify which labels are
>   associated with a message or thread by calling `messages.modify` or
>   `threads.modify`, respectively.

So the only workaround is to use

```
label.addToThread(message.getThread());
```

after sending the draft.

Comment: I am a bit confused: the first code snippet in the question does add a label to the draft—or at least the thread associated with the draft. Labels can also be manually added on the gmail page: and those don't disappear when I click "send". Why the discrepancy? And is all of this consistent with the documentation snippet you quoted?

Comment: What I meant is that any draft messages cannot have labels applied to them. Adding label before sending the draft will not take effect. So you can only add label after sending the draft message.